# Increment array index after rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, rake, rake-task

So I've got an array of strings that I want to send to my Rails logger. What I want is after each rake task run, my index is incremented by one so that the next string is posts in the logger. I have tried this the traditional way of using class variables and using Redis. My index is refusing to increment. This is what I have tried.

TRY 1

accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  cattr_accessor :index
  @@index ||= 0

  def self.post
    current_user = User.find_by(:id => 1)
    user_posts = current_user.accounts.find_by(:id => 1).posts
    Rails.logger.info user_posts[@@index].tweet
  end
end
```

post.rake

```
desc 'send post to twitter'
task send_posts: :environment do
  AccountsController.post
  AccountsController.index += 1
end
```

In the second try I try to use Redis to make my `@@index` variable persistent. Still no increment.

accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  cattr_accessor :index
  @@index = $redis.set('index', 0)

  def self.post
    current_user = User.find_by(:id => 1)
    user_posts = current_user.accounts.find_by(:id => 1).posts
    Rails.logger.info user_posts[@@index.to_i].tweet
  end
end
```

post.rake

```
desc 'send post to twitter'
task send_posts: :environment do
  AccountsController.post
  #AccountsController.index += 1
  $redis.incr('index')
end
```

Can someone help me iterate over the array AFTER EACH rake task run?

Comment: variable will reset when you load the environment, which will happen every time that rake task gets run. What are you ultimately trying to do? What's the end goal? To log all of the tweets?

Comment: yes to log the tweets periodically...all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store the incremented value **outside the rails code** because Rails is genuinely loaded every time the rake task runs (the state is in no way preserved in between the rake runs). So, use the Redis approach.

Then, you can just use the `incr` method in your task, just as you already do. According to [the documentation](http://redis.io/commands/incr), `incr` will set the value under the key to 0 before incrementing, if the key does not exist.

Finally, do not set the value to 0 in your controller, otherwise you'll practically reset the value during each run of the rake task. Instead, use just `get` to get the current value from Redis:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  cattr_accessor :index
  @@index = $redis.get('index') || 0
end
```

And that should be it.

Answer (score 2):

and why not just do all of that in a loop inside the rake task? why bother with incrementing that variable? You can put it all inside your rake task.

```
User.find_each do |user|
  user_posts = []
  user.accounts.each { |account| user_posts << account.posts }
  user_posts.each { |post| Rails.logger.info post.tweet }
end
```

Comment: no. how periodic the posts will be made will be set by each user. the frequency of post for each user will be different. the users choose how frequent the posts should got out. it's not fixed.

Comment: In that case...to maintain access to the environment, a worker is better than a rake task.